# Injecting Component name into tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This has been asked before, but the solutions don't seem to be working for me... maybe because I am conditionally rendering?  The idea is that I have choices for the user to click on, and then the appropriate component is rendered onClick.  So I want to inject the name of the component into the tag conditionally when the user makes a choice.  Here is a fairly minimal example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { setData } from '../../actions/data';
import * as mathUtils from '../../mathUtils';

class MyParentClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChoice = this.handleChoice.bind(this);
  }
  handleChoice({ topic, user }) {
    const id = `${Date.now()}-${mathUtils.uuidv4()}`;
    this.props.setData({ topic, id, user });
  }
  render() {
    const { id, currentUser } = this.props;
    const Topic = this.props.topic;
    return (
      id
        ? <Topic />
        : <RaisedButton
            role="button"
            primary={true}
            label="NumberOne"
            onClick={() => this.handleChoice({
                topic: 'NumberOne',
                user: currentUser
              })
            }
          />
          <br />
          <RaisedButton
            role="button"
            primary={true}
            label="NumberTwo"
            onClick={() => this.handleChoice({
                topic: 'NumberTwo',
                user: currentUser
              })
            }
          />
    );
  }
}

MyParentClass.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  topic: PropTypes.string,
  setData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  currentUser: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

MyParentClass.defaultProps = {
  id: null,
  topic: null
};

export default connect(
  ({ session, data }) => ({
    currentUser: session.currentUser,
    id: data.id,
    topic: data.topic
  }),
  { setData }
)(MyParentClass);
```

I get two different errors in the console for this code that seem to be at odds with each other.  The first is `Warning: <NumberOne /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.` and the second is `Warning: The tag <NumberOne> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.`

I'm reasonably convinced I'm just not applying the correct logic to my application, but I'm not sure how else to accomplish the desired behavior.

Comment: You are missing open tag for `div`.Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly set the `element` instead of `string`. First `import` your components like

```
import NumberOne from '../../NumberOne';
```

Then, in your `onClick` set the respective component like

```
onClick={() => this.handleChoice({
            topic: NumberOne,
            user: currentUser
          })
```

The rest of your code as it is with the above changes should work for you.

Comment: Yep, exactly this.  Thanks so much, I've been staring at this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in your case `topic` should be a jsx function, not a string.

For example, pseudocode:

```
// Outer render
render() {
    const topicOne = (props) => (<div>Topic One</div>);
    const topicTwo = (props) => (<div>Topic Two</div>);

    return (<MyParentClass topic={topicTwo} />);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your react-router-dom version (beta.6) is incompatible with mdbreact library. If you install stable version ^5.3.3 everything will work fine.

Here are some links with react-router-dom releases and docs:

https://libraries.io/npm/react-router-dom